# Btrieve record Locking issue

Tags: btrieve

I am experiencing a file contention issue I believe is related to increased user load.

My system specifications:

- VB.net UI/NetCOBOL
- business logic/Btrieve
- file access using a Pervasive DB.

I am seeing record locking between users who are attempting to process Sale Orders with the same Item IDs even though each individual sale order item process is wrapped in a transaction object and the parent sale order record is explicitly locked as it should be.

I can track this scenario existing back several years/releases but it only became an issue recently due to what I believe to be increased activity across increased multi-user load.

The file access methodology is purely Pessimistic and the file structures are ISAM in nature, not relational.
Anybody have any insights please?

Comment: What Btrieve status codes are you seeing when this happens?

Comment: Status code 84 as in locked record. The thing is that the records are detail records and are wrapped by a TTS and the time in the record is as minimized as possible for obvious reasons. I watched the locked with Bill Bach's suggested FileLock tool and they appear to be functioning correctly. What happens is 2 or more users might have a large saleorder with many items on it all the same ID number and as they are trying to work with them they are getting locking and associated errors